# Created a simple gem, but irb can't see it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a simple gem by doing:

1. testgem.gemspec

   ```
   Gem::Specification.new do |s|
     s.name = 'testgem'
     s.version = '0.0.1'
     s.summary = "code generation"
     s.authors = ['asdf']
   end
   ```
2. created the following file layout:

   ```
   testgem.gemspec
   Gemfile
   lib/
   lib/testgem.rb
   lib/testgem/other.rb
   ```
3. ran the following:

   ```
   gem build testgem.gemspec

   WARNING:  no description specified
   WARNING:  no email specified
   WARNING:  no homepage specified
   Successfully built RubyGem
   Name: testgem
   Version: 0.0.1
   File: testgem-0.0.1.gem
   ```
4. installed it:

   ```
   gem install ./testgem-0.0.1.gem 
   Successfully installed testgem-0.0.1
   1 gem installed
   ```
5. tested to see if irb can see it:

   ```
   irb
   require 'testgem'
   oadError: cannot load such file -- testgem
   ```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p194

It seems to be installed if I do:

```
gem list
..
testgem (0.0.1)
..
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: what `gem which testgem` shows?

Comment: it says 'ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library testgem'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  need to add your lib to the search path. Just add

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
```

on top of your .gemspec

Answer (score 1):

When you use `require` in Ruby, you are trying to load a *file*, not a *gem*. The file could of course be contained in a gem, and by convention a gem will have a file with the same name as the gem itself so that if you wanted to use the gem `foo` you would use `require 'foo'`. This isn’t always the case though, for example to use the [`bcrypt-ruby`](https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby) gem you need to `require 'bcrypt'`.

Additionally a gem doesn’t necessarily have to contain *any* filles at all. An example of this is the `rails` gem, which doesn’t contain any files itself (at least in version 3.2), but has dependencies to the various Rails components, so that you can install them all in one step.

In your case, although you have a `lib/testgem.rb` file in your gems project directory, you are not including it in your gem. You need to specify which [files should be included](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files), the default is to not include anything.

To simply include all the files in your project directory, you can add something like:

```
s.files = Dir.glob '**/*'
```

to your gemspec.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `require 'rubygems'` first.

Comment: I did that already, and I believe in 1.9.3 you don't have to.  I did require 'rubygems' and it returned false, so it was already loaded.

Comment: Doing this is a no-op in Ruby 1.9.